# py2exe missing distutils modules in virtualenv

Tags: python, pandas, virtualenv, py2exe, distutils

I am trying to build executable file of my project(Python 2.7.5) but getting this below error when trying to run the executable.
   `ERROR \ProjectPython\library.zip\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv 
   distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "main.py", line 130, in <module>
       ...
       File "pandas\compat\__init__.pyo", line 32,in <module>
       File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
       File "distutils\__init__.pyo", line 25, in <module>
          ERROR ImportError: cannot import name dist`

After searching for solutions to this issue, I got to know that this must be because of distutils in virtualenv is different from whats in Python installation Lib directory. So, I have been trying to exclude/remove distutils in virtualenv and add distutils package of my origin interpreter during executable build.
That exact solution exists for cxfreeze, but couldn't find alternate solution for py2exe. My setup.py options looks something like

```
distutils.core.setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {
        "compressed": 1,
        "optimize": 1,
        "bundle_files": 1,
        "packages": ['psycopg2', 'lxml', 'sqlalchemy', 'openpyxl', 'pandas', 'numpy']
    }}
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Similar question answered when using cxFreeze https://gist.github.com/nicoddemus/ca0acd93a20acbc42d1d 
I want exact same thing, but with py2exe

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you've shared, it seems that you might be going the wrong direction with excluding distutils. The error (warning) is stating that `distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils`.

Try creating a fresh virtual environment with the needed libraries and building again.

Comment: I have copied this error from logs after executable is build. The application works on OS where there is no Python interpreter, as it uses the virtualenv for this purpose. That is the reason the warning shows as distutils is present in same location as system distutils. I want to be able to remove this distutils present in virtualenv and replace it with distutils package from original Python interpreter of dev environment before executable is build using py2exe.